# Insert String array into list of model in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to insert String array to list object / list model?

My result String array:

`[198507282014041001, 199001312019031018, 199112212019031014, 197710232002121001]`

I wanna add my string to my model, this my model:

```
class Tag {
  final String id;

  Tag(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```dart
List<String> stringList = [
  "198507282014041001",
  "199001312019031018",
  "199112212019031014",
  "197710232002121001",
];

List<Tag> tagList = stringList.map((e) => Tag(e)).toList();

print(tagList.map((e) => e.id).toList()); // Check if there is already data in the model
```

Comment: how we know the data is already inside the model?